# Time Stamp using asp.net, vb.net and ms-access

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

I'm using Microsoft access with asp.net and vb.net to create a form page. I'd like to get the timestamp once I click on the save button. I managed to use this line of code to do that

```
 Dim time1 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Quest(TimeUS1) VALUES (Now())", cn)

time1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

However, it saves both the date and time. I'm only interested in time.Any idea on how to only extract time ?

Really appreciate your time here.

Comment: Save it as seconds from midnight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the built-in `Time()` function

```
 Dim time1 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Quest(TimeUS1) VALUES (Time())", cn)

time1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```